# FME Querying an Microsoft SQL Server Non-Spatial to perform an attribute join

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

I am trying to join a spatial table with some values coming from a MS SQL table.

I have it working properly with an [excel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326804/fme-merge-two-files-that-only-have-some-attributes-the-same/326878#326878) but when I try to use SQLExecutor or SQLCreator I get stuck where the DatabaseJoiner only allows me to choose SQL tables and not the result of the SQLCreator.

[image]

[image]

But in the DBJoiner I can't get the reader to be the result from the SQL
[image]

Do I have to write to a csv/excel and then read use this for the db joiner? it's best to avoid the creation of files even if temporary.

**UPDATE:**
I need to run the query to get the fields I need to join from the MSSQL -they aren't in a table but a result of a query.

Basically the process is.
1. Get current cadastre and clean it to be in the format we require (done as part of [FME Merge two files that only have some attributes the same](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326804/fme-merge-two-files-that-only-have-some-attributes-the-same/326878#326878))
2. Perform 3 sets of queries from the db that *a -match lot plan to the council's land_no and get some address fields, *b -use the land_no and get a property no from a second query, *c -use the property number to get the owner info and put this into the table.

3- the queries seem to work fine but when I use DB Joiner of Feature Joiner it's overwriting the fields that were previously populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the DatabaseJoiner transformer to join with a SQL database; just as you do with Excel.

Is there a reason you have the SQLExecutor/Creator there? If it's to do some sort of pre-query of the data (which I don't honestly think should be necessary) then use a FeatureJoiner instead of the DatabaseJoiner.

Basically:

- **FeatureJoiner** has two input ports for when both sets of data to join are already being read into the workspace.
- **DatabaseJoiner** has a single input port for when one set of data is in the workspace and the other set exists in a database elsewhere.

Or check out the Prefetch Query setting in the DatabaseJoiner, which might be another way to avoid the SQLCreator.

Comment: I've been trying this but it doesn't work. I'll update the question.